# xquery beginner- how to give a specific default value to a variable when there is no content in xml for that variable

Tags: xquery

I am working to extract some content from a web page.

Given below is the XQuery code I am using. I am using a XQuery library to parse through XML which is obtained by transforming a HTML web page into XML. After that I am extracting some specific content from that XML page:

```
declare variable $doc as node() external;

let $select_block := $doc//div[@class="randomclass" and contains(.,'MatchingText')]
for $select_link in $select_block/a 
for $select_link_url in $select_link/@href
where contains($assignee_link_url, 'inassignee')  
return data($select_link)
```

From above, you can see that variable `$select_block` tries to extract content of that div of web page which has `class="randomclass"`, and which contains the text "MatchingText".

Now, if the web page in question does not contain such a block, then how do I return a default value for `$select_link`? Basically, I want to tackle the scenario where no value is returned for a selection within an XQuery expression  so that I can mark a flag that tells the user that this value was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An if/then/else construct will probably do what you want. An example:

```
declare variable $doc as node() external;

let $select_block := $doc//div[@class="randomclass" and contains(.,'MatchingText')]
return if($select_block) then (
  for $select_link in $select_block/a 
  for $select_link_url in $select_link/@href
    where  contains($assignee_link_url,'inassignee')  
  return data($select_link)
) else (
  'default value'
)
```

Comment: -- is the xquery above correct? I can see one 'return' before the 'if'(which I think should not be there...)... Also shouldnt there be another return before 'default value' ? Thanks...

Comment: @ChristianGrün - if I want to give 3 different outputs-- one that checks for existence of "select_block", one that checks for existence of "select_link" and 3rd one that gives output as usual... how do I create a if.. then..else if... else ? Is such a construct permitted in Xquery? Can you kindly provide such a construct for the example above (with 3 scenarios)? Thanks a lot...

Comment: @ChristianGrün i found some examples of nested if-then-else.. thank you for your help...

Comment: Good to hear you resolved the problem. A last note: due to the functional nature of XQuery, all expressions (including if/then/else) can be placed nearly everywhere in a query..